# Appending text to each item in list

Tags: python

I would like to add the word days to appear after each item in my list (each item is a numpy.int64) such that each item appears followed by the word days (e.g 6 days).

This is what I have tried so far

```
medians =  closing_deals.groupby(['origin'])['days_to_close'].median().values
median_labels = [m + 'days' for m in medians]
```

Here is my data

```
array([ 9, 11,  7, 27, 13, 42, 35, 10,  9, 23, 17])
```

This is the error message I am receiving

> TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching
>   types dtype

Comment: What's wrong with what you have tried?

Comment: @Austin Sorry forgot to add, this is my error message "TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')"

Comment: You're trying to add an integer and a string.  The error message says that you haven't defined any such vectorized function.  Try `str(m) + 'days'`.  If you still have troubles, please include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help effectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't concatenate int with string using `+`, but you can use string formatting to get the output you are looking for. For example:

```
medians = [9, 11, 7, 27, 13, 42, 35, 10, 9, 23, 17]
labels = [f'{m} days' for m in medians]
print(labels)
# ['9 days', '11 days', '7 days', '27 days', '13 days', '42 days', '35 days', '10 days', '9 days', '23 days', '17 days']

# For Python 3 versions before 3.6, use '{} days'.format(m) instead of the f string
```